# File Upload using file input with Ionic (Selection of file using Native File Browser )

Tags: android, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

In my ionic app  markup i have

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

in my controller i am getting the file on selection from file manager

```
 fileinput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);
```

This works well when i upload images or videos .and also if use the file manager  option from the image below . but i encounter problems when uploading audio from quick links list or if use third party browser to get the file. in most other case the File object is returned and i can upload it successfully .

[image]

but i am encountering two problems

1) when i use the quick links on the sidebar to upload an audio file which lists all audio files with their names .On clicking a file from this list i do not get the extension nor the content-type in the file object  which i need . But the same works if i use the file manager options and navigate to the file . it's almost as if the audio quick link list just has few details and does not have extension or content-type details .

[image]

2) If i use the third -party explorer like ES explorer or the music app shown in sidebar of the image  the App crashes and stops .

So is there any other way to navigate to a file to upload from the app or am i doing something wrong . ImagePicker cordova plugin's . limitation of just choosing images is the problem or else would have used that

Comment: I am facing the same issue . do you find answer to that

Comment: @sam yes  i used https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser . 
this worked fine .. returned me the native path ..which i could convert later

Comment: I used the same plugin and resolved it later with `cordovafilepath` plugin. Thanks man

Comment: check the sd card permission. This happens due to permission not granted to sd card.

Comment: Is there any workaround by using html input? I don't want to use the cordova-filechooser plugin. Is there any way without using the plugin? I am not getting the content type when i am trying to upload a pdf file. I need for both iOS and Android

Comment: @SetuBasak Don't think so . Since the cordova-filechooser is like an interface over the phone's native way of choosing a file for upload . (and doing things like opening file manager ) . This was a while back though . You can try if modern webviews can comprehend that .

Answer (score 1):

Android does not give the original file name and file type using the above approachand it is a security issue from android. So, i had to make below solution for retrieving the correct file name, file type, file size and the file data in base64.

You can follow my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49787899/4299527).